# angular ngx-material-timepicker can't customize

Tags: angular, angular-material, styling, timepicker

I try to use ngx-material-timepicker like code below but I can't change any CSS classes
I'm following this link https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-material-timepicker

**This is my code**

```
 <div class="clock">
    <input placeholder="24hr format" aria-label="24hr format" [ngxTimepicker]="fullTime" [format]="24" readonly />
                  <ngx-material-timepicker
                    [appendToInput]="true"
                    [disableAnimation]="true"
                    [theme]="oktTheme"
                    (timeSet)="onTimeset($event)"
                    #fullTime
                  ></ngx-material-timepicker>
  </div>
```

**this is ts code**

```
  oktTheme = {
    container: {
      bodyBackgroundColor: "#424242",
      buttonColor: "#fff"
    },
    dial: {
      dialBackgroundColor: "#555"
    },
    clockFace: {
      clockFaceBackgroundColor: "#555",
      clockHandColor: "#01806b",
      clockFaceTimeInactiveColor: "#fff"
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 6):

solve this problem whit add custome class to directive and set it in style.scss by using inner directive classes

**html**

```
 <div class="clock">
                  <input placeholder="24hr format" aria-label="24hr format" [ngxTimepicker]="fullTime" [format]="24" readonly />
                  <ngx-material-timepicker
                    [appendToInput]="true"
                    [disableAnimation]="true"
                    [theme]="oktTheme"
                    [timepickerClass]="'custome-class'"
                    (timeSet)="onTimeset($event)"
                    #fullTime
                  ></ngx-material-timepicker>
</div>
```

**style.scss**

```
.custome-class {
  direction: ltr;
  .timepicker__header {
    padding: 0px 30px !important;
    border-top-right-radius: 12px;
    border-top-left-radius: 12px;
  }
  .timepicker-dial__control {
    font-size: 20px !important;
  }

  .timepicker-dial {
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 44px;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

**place this in your SCSS file (in app.component.scss or your specific component)**

```
::ng-deep ngx-material-timepicker-content{
  --body-background-color: #fff;
  --primary-font-family: 'Roboto',sans-serif;
  --button-color: #c6ff00 !important;
  --dial-active-color: #fff;
  --dial-inactive-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .5);
  --dial-background-color: #c6ff00 !important;
  --dial-editable-active-color: #c6ff00 !important;
  --dial-editable-background-color: #fff;
  --clock-face-time-active-color: #fff;
  --clock-face-time-inactive-color: #6c6c6c;
  --clock-face-inner-time-inactive-color: #929292;
  --clock-face-time-disabled-color: #c5c5c5;
  --clock-face-background-color: #f0f0f0;
  --clock-hand-color: #c6ff00 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Change color for header, buttons and clock hand.

```
.ngx-picker-custom {
  direction: ltr;
  .timepicker__header {
    background-color: var(--color-cyan)!important;
  }
  .timepicker-button{
    color: var(--color-cyan)!important;
  }
  .clock-face__clock-hand,
  .clock-face__number > span.active,
  .clock-face__clock-hand{
    background-color: var(--color-cyan)!important;
  }
  .clock-face__clock-hand_minute:before {
    border-color: var(--color-cyan)!important;
  }
}
```